# How do I reorder the Account Create section of the woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The Account Creation section of the woocommerce checkout page has two fields:
1. Create account password
2. Account username

I want to reorder these two fields so that 1. Create account password is below 2. Account username

I want "Account username" first and "Create account password" second.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please read carefully [Overriding templates via a theme documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) that will explain you how to change templates code via your active theme. Then you will have to edit the template `myaccount/form-login.php` and reorder some fields blocks in it, as you want.

Answer (score 0):

In woocommerce template you need to overwrite my account folder and in that you can get all related files for account page file is form-login.php